# iOS6 Facebook 3.1.1 SDK: No AdSupport framework

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

To keep it simple, I've installed the SDK and for some reason cannot seem to find the Adsupport framework. The Social and Accounts frameworks are added with no issue, but the Adsupport one is even missing from the samples included with the SDK.

Have I missed something? I'm on iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5, I've added the SDK and FacebookSDKResources.bundle, and then added the two frameworks and just can't see the third.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be under ios6.

[image: adsupport framework]

However, I have also had this happen to me, but in my case social, accounts and adsupport were all missing. It turned out they were in the trash. I was also playing around with the facebook sdks at the time so maybe something in the installation steps can make you accidentally delete them? Worst case scenario is reinstall xcode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately it's not in there. I've tried reinstalling the SDK to no avail. It's odd, it states that the frameworks are optional, so I removed it and then I get an error stating that "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager" cannot find something it's dependent on. I guess I'll have to try  a reinstall of Xcode - thanks.

Comment: it doesn't come with the facebook sdk so that wouldn't help. But try looking in here: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/frameworks. If its a no go maybe reinstalling Xcode is the only thing left to do :(